# how to add a custom nsview in the header of default nswindow?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macros

I want to add some controls to header, for that i add controls to view and now want to add view in the header of window. I am new in cocoa, so don't know, how to do that?
Need some help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to add that. But when i needed i change property of NSWindow. In property click on Texture Property. By this whole window look same including header. Now you can add NSView or NSBox on NSWindow to give your design.